# jQuery simple wysiwyg replacements

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, wysiwyg

my html.

```
<div class="wysiwyg">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="wysiwyg-preview"></div>
```

now my js.

```
var wysiwyg_val;

    $('.wysiwyg textarea').live('keyup',function(){

         wysiwyg_val = $(this).val();

        wysiwyg_val = wysiwyg_val
        .replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
        .replace(/<br>/g,'[br]')
        .replace(/\</g,'&lt;')
        .replace(/\>/g,'&gt;')
        .replace(/\{code}(.*){\/code}/g, '<pre class="prettyprint"><code>$1</code></pre>')
        .replace(/\[br\]/g,'<br>');


        $('.wysiwyg-preview').html(wysiwyg_val);



     });
```

i'm trying replacing `{code} $content {/code} with <pre><code> $content </code></pre>` and it works, but it works only at first time that i put `{code} some content{/code}` inside the textarea, then from the second time that i put same `{code} some content{/code}` it shows all inside the first `<pre><code></code></pre>` , how can i attach the replacement to all the `{code}$content{/code}` founded and not only at the first founded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of characters that need escaping in the regex. I messed around with it and made [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/T2vAV/)

Oh and using `live` didn't seem to cooperate with me at first, so I switched it to `bind` and just forgot to switch it back... is it really necessary?

```
var wysiwyg_val;

$('.wysiwyg textarea').bind('keyup', function() {

    wysiwyg_val = $(this).val()
        .replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
        .replace(/\<br\/\>/g, '[br]')
        .replace(/\</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/\>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/\{code\}/g, '<pre class="prettyprint"><code>')
        .replace(/\{\/code\}/g, '</code></pre>')
        .replace(/\[br\]/g, '<br>');

    $('.wysiwyg-preview').html(wysiwyg_val);

});
```

I'm not sure why the `\n` are replaced with `<br>` then changing the escaping the angled brackets, because you can see them in the result, maybe convert the `\n` at the end of the replacement block?

Comment: well your code is really ok and the mess was about these 2 lines     .replace(/\{code\}/g, '<pre class="prettyprint"><code>')
        .replace(/\{\/code\}/g, '</code></pre>')

Comment: i turned to live() just cause sometimes i $.load() dinamically modules that has this script inside :P

Comment: I ran the code through jsLint, and it doesn't like using `.` inside of regex, so I figured why not just split that line into two.

Comment: "." where? .replace() you mean?

Comment: In this original replace `.replace(/\{code}(.*){\/code}/g, '<pre class="prettyprint"><code>$1</code></pre>')`